# Story about a man who can predict future but commits suicide due to this ability

Tags: story-identification

This was a short story that belonged to a collection of sci-fi stories. The story is narrated by a woman who is mesmerised with the protagonist and his abilities to anticipate things.  In the end,  it's revealed that he had the ability to predict the future and ironically commits suicide. I can't recall the name of this collection /volume.

Would also really appreciate name of the author.

Edit: I read this story around 2004-05. It belonged to a book with numerous short sci-fi stories by different authors

Comment: It would help narrow it down if you could recall roughly what year it was published and/or what year you read it.  Also, if you remember anything about any of the other stories in the collection, or what the cover looked like, that'd be very helpful.  Do you recall whether this was a book or a magazine (such as Asimov or Weird Tales)?

Comment: Added some more information about the story.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly ["Fivesight"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62041) from Spider Robinson.  [More info here](http://callahans.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=fivesight&fulltext=Search)

Kathy Anders admires her husband Cass Anders for his ability to see the future.  After they've been married a while, though, she begin to have trouble living with him.  She has an affair, and is afraid he has seen it and is going to kill her lover.  Cass, however, commits suicide.

Comment: This is close. As far as I remember,  the woman meets the man only for a day.  Also,  the man commits suicide because he can't look forward to anything in life.

Comment: Cass Anders. LOL.